# CAKEPHP: conditions com AND

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2

Estou com uma dúvida ao efetuar uma busca.

O item conditions na minha atual consulta está dessa maneira:

```
'conditions'=>array(
    'Produto.publicado'=>1,
    'Produto.titulo LIKE'=>"%$kw%",
    'TagsProduto.tag_id'=>$tags
),
```

Porém, $tags é um array e ele vai interpretar e implicitar o IN na busca. Eu preciso que ele busque incrementando, ou seja, com AND.

Alguém sabe como proceder?

Comment: poderia postar um exemplo do array $tags? Fica mais fácil entender.

Answer (score 1):

Meu caro coleta,

Da maneira que você está relacioando as TAGs não é viável, fazer.

Pense que trazer produtos com obrigatoriamente as TAGs A, B e C, teriam que ter subquerys:

```
<?php
$criterios = array(
    'Produto.publicado'=>1,
    'Produto.titulo LIKE'=>"%$kw%",
    'AND' => array(),
);
foreach ($tags as $tag){
    $criterios['AND'][] = array('TagsProduto.tag_id'=>$tag);
}
?>
```

Veja acima uma forma de fazer o que você quer, porém não tem sentido, pois TagsProduto.id tem apenas 1 valor na linha, ou 1 ID da TagsProduto por linha.

Para trazer produtos com as TAGs A, B e C, você tem que fazer algo como:

```
<?php
$prodTag = array();
foreach ($tags as $tag){
    $prodTag[] = "Produto.id = (SELECT produto_id FROM tags_produto WHERE id={$tag} AND produto_id=Produto.id)";
}
$tags = implode(' AND ', $prodTags);

$this->Produto->find('all', array('conditions'=>array(
    $tags,
)));
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado, Newton! =)

Answer (score 0):

Tente esses exemplos de AND/OR

```
         $conditons = array(
            'conditions'=>array(
                'AND' => array(
                    array('Produto.publicado'=>1,),
                    array('Produto.titulo LIKE'=>"%$kw%",),
                    array('TagsProduto.tag_id'=>$tags),
                )
            ),
        );

        $conditons = array(
            'conditions'=>array(
                'OR' => array(
                    array('Produto.publicado'=>1,),
                    array('Produto.titulo LIKE'=>"%$kw%",),
                    array('TagsProduto.tag_id'=>$tags),
                )
            ),
        );
```